# Out of range value for column 'contact_no' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to add a number with a length of 11 but when I input it in the database it can't.  If I try to add a number with a length of 10 it can.

This is the error:

```
ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'contact_no' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `mcs`.`new_table` (`id`, `contact_no`) VALUES ('1', '12345678901')
```

Comment: This problem seems pretty straightforward - you don't have enough enough storage allocated for the column.  Can you share your column definition?

Comment: Was this a question. or just a status report?

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what question you are asking.

**Why is this error being returned?**

Likely, the `contact_no` column is declared with datatype of `INT`, a 32-bit integer, and you attempted to assign a value larger than the supported maximum value.

The maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer is 2,147,483,647. (that decimal value of 2^31-1. For an unsigned 32-bit integer, maximum value is 2^32.)

**Some other question that wasn't asked**

If you need to store values larger than the maximum supported by the INT datatype, you could define the column as a different datatype.

For example, BIGINT gives a maximum value of 2^63-1 for unsigned.

If you need a maximum of 12 decimal digits, you could use a `DECIMAL(12)` datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Change your data type of `contact_no` to `BIGINT`.
Check range of different data type at [MYSQL official website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).
I personally recommend you to use varchar, as you don't need to compare contact number with any field.

Answer (score 0):

Please check datatype of contact_no column.
'12345678901' is exceeding its size.